# Pymol python script for selecting a residue's sidechain and calculating its center of mass

Tags: python, pymol

I trying to write a pythonic PyMol script that loads a PDB, cmd.iterates through the PDB and stores the residues (three letter code) into an array.  I then want to loop through this array and calculate the center of masses (COM) of each aa's sidechains (except gly) and add it into a second array.  I am able to calculate the COM of a residue as a whole, i.e. including backbone atoms.  But what I want to calculate is the COM of the sidechain.  Please point me in the right direction.

```
path = 'Path to PDB dir'
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.PDB')):
    cmd.load(filename)  
    stored_residues = []
    cmd.iterate('name ca', 'stored_residues.append(resn)')

    stored_residues_COM = []

    for i in stored_residues:
         stored_residues_sidechain_COM.append(centerOfMass('resn %s' % i))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you used the command `pymol.cmd.centerofmass`? If so the selector is the ticket to doing it by selecting everything of the residue bar the backbone atoms, e.g. f'resi {r} not name N+CA+C+O+H'

Parenthetically, the `cmd.iterate` command is really ugly and counter-intuitive —it's heavily used because it is older. The command `get_model(selection)` in pymol2 module is so much nicer.

```
for atom in pymol.cmd.get_model('name CA').atom:
     atom.resi #note it is type str due to insertion codes!
     atom.resn
     atom.coords # List[float]
```

Second parenthesis. A `and not element H` is not needed or beneficial to `pymol.cmd.centerofmass` as this takes account of mass and occupancy. There is no need to select only heavy atoms as a proton weighs nothing. The barycentre and centroid are the same in geometry where there is no mass to the points, but here mass is present.

Comment: That is good advice.  Thank you.  I am also looking at Thomas Holder's code (https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Sidechaincenters) as a comparative approach.

Comment: @gwot Upvoting and checking 'answer resolved' is a good way to say thanks

Comment: Hi Matteo, sorry for the breach of etiquette.  I have accepted you helpful answer, but do not yet have the rep to upvote.